# A single case sensitive and non-case sensitive dual search criteria in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Ok, I have two columns. H and K

H is case sensitive, K is not.

I have written a formula that "should" work.  But for some reason, it doesn't.  I used to know how to do this about a decade ago, but as they say, you don't use specific muscles for a long enough period of time you lose strength in it.

```
=IF(H2="*New Hire*", IF(K2="open", "True", "False "))
```

I want it so that H2 and K2 if both are true, they show an answer of true, while if not, it's shown as false.

Can someone please help me? I can do this manually if I need to, but I have over 10,000 lines to go through and this would make my life so much easier.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May not have fully understood what you want, but perhaps this (FIND is case-sensitive):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("New Hire",H2)), IF(K2="open", "True", "False "))
```

or perhaps

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(FIND("New Hire",H2)), ISNUMBER(FIND("open",K2))), "True", "False "))
```

Depends how strict is the case sensitive requirement.

Comment: `=AND(ISNUMBER(FIND("New Hire,H2)),K2="open")`?

Comment: @BigBen- yes, that is better. I can see now you've posted an answer so if that does the trick might remove this anyway.

Comment: Eh, keep it, it's the case-sensitive option.

Comment: @BigBen- but not sure if it meets OP's requirement. But COUNTIFS is case insensitive?

Comment: COUNTIFS is case insensitive, yes.

Comment: Ta, couldn't remember.